# Анонимная функция в PHP

Tags: php, функции

Здравствуйте.

Нужна некая функция:

```
mixed remember(string $key, DateTime|int $minutes, Closure $callback)
```

Приблизительное использование:

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function () use($db) {
  return $db::table('users')->get();
});
```

Функция будет работать с кешем Redis.   
Суть такая:  
1-й параметр - ключ записи в Redis, если он есть - возвращает его значение, если нету - выполняется анонимная функция и значение сохраняется в Redis с ключом (параметр 1).

Мой текущий вариант:

```
public function remember($key, $ttl=300, $value ) {
    if( $this->exists($key) ){
        return $this->get($key);
    }else{              
        $return = $value;
        $this->set($key, $return, $ttl);
        return $return; 
    }
}
```

Но он не работает.

Как мне пожно подправить так, чтобы работало?

Спасибо.

Comment: .

    if (is_callable($value)) {
        $value = call_user_func($value);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function remember($key, $ttl=300, $value ) {
    if( $this->exists($key) ){
        return $this->get($key);
    }else{
        if ($value instanceof Closure) {
            $return = call_user_func($value);
        } else {
            $return = $value;
        }
        $this->set($key, $return, $ttl);
        return $return; 
    }
}
```